# Correct form of the irregular verb in this context

Tags: verbs, past-tense, past-participles, irregular-forms

> Have you ever eaten that steak?

(Correct I assume)

Normally I guess people would say "Have you had that steak" or "Have you had that juice?" And I'm inclined to think that the verb to be used is the past perfect one. So in-case I want to use the verbs, eat or drink, what is the appropriate form of the verb to be used?

- > Have you ever drunk that juice ?
- > Have you ever drank that juice ?

Comment: We cannot tell what you are really asking here. Are you asking which form of the verb is used in perfect constructions? Surely this is given by any reference book on English. Also, what is this "among" bit referring to? First, I suspect "among" makes no sense there, but which things is "these" referring to? You’ve asked for elementary subject–predicate analysis of basic sentences; even were it edited to make it suitable for a site catering to “linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts”  (which it is not currently) that’s still too many questions. Maybe try [ell.se]?

Comment: I changed it a bit. Is it acceptable now?

Comment: I’m going to migrate it to [ell.se] because these are quite basic questions, not really linguistic ones.

Comment: The ***drunk/drank*** distinction is the same as ***seen/saw***, so just as we never ask *Have you ever **saw** that movie?*, we shouldn't use ***drank*** in OP's context. But for this particular verb, even some native speakers sometimes get it wrong. It's not always a hanging offence (unless you're asking a real pedant! :), but there aren't all that many irregular verbs in English (the problem simply doesn't arise with regular verbs such as *Have you ever **watched** that movie?*), so it's probably worth just sitting down and learning them all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree. Irregular verbs is just something that needs learning - my child is currently at that stage in his English lessons. Be grateful that the number is comparatively small and that English verbs aren't really conjugated...

Comment: @Stephie: An added bonus is that for *most* of the [50 most common irregular verbs,](http://www.esl-lounge.com/reference/grammar-reference-most-common-irregular-verb-list.php) the Past Tense and Past Participle are the same (as with regular verbs), so it's nowhere near as daunting as it might first appear. Besides which, there are only a couple of hundred you'd ever encounter today (and many native speakers might not even know all of *them*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers _Drink, drank, drunk_ has spawned others. In baseball (you know, the manly sport from which the incomprehensible game of cricket is descended) a player slides into the base. Dizzy Dean was famous in St. Louis for conjugating _slide_ as **_slɑ:d, slíju:d, slʊd_**.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few English irregular verbs with *ing* or *ink* that follow the below pattern.  Drink is in this group.

```
Present     Past        Past-Participle (have/had + X)
----------- ----------- ---------------
drink       drank       drunk
spring      sprang      sprung
ring        rang        rung
sing        sang        sung
stink       stank       stunk
shrink      shrank      shrunk
sink        sank        sunk
```

English, being riddled with exceptions, also has exceptions to the exceptions.  The following words don't quite follow the above pattern (though you probably could get away with *slang*):

```
swing       swung       swung
string      strung      strung
sting       stung       stung
sling       slung       slung
fling       flung       flung
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Have/has+past participle*. This pattern  is used to form the present perfect. You should just learn common irregular verbs, there is no other way (drink-drank-drunk) and use them correctly.
>
> Have you ever *drunk* that juice?